# Thank You to Manager

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I sent an email to my manager with the information he asked and he responded back that "Thank you for the details and hope you are well".

Should I respond back that "I'm doing good and thank you for asking " or is it not needed?
I am just confused that "Hope all is well" is just an ending note or a question?

P.S- I donot get to meet my team/manager very often.

Comment: Indeed this is opinion based, but I would not reply to that, as it seems he is just being polite. Even if there was a question mark in his sentence I would think twice in case it was just rhetorical question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am just confused that "Hope all is well" is just an ending note or a question?

It's just politeness.  No need for a specific reply.

Comment: Except maybe if your previous communication was about a problem you had, health or something similar, in which case "hope you are well" would be a polite way of inquiring after news. Otherwise, "It's just politeness. No need for a specific reply."